# ASP.NET MVC Async task run does it make sense?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, async-await, task-parallel-library, task, threadpool

please tell my, does it make sense ? - in controller write async method but without async operations, i mean next record:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> SendTask(TaskModel taskModel)
    {
        MailTask task = taskModel.BuildTask();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
                task.Send(); // <- it is not async method

               // bla bla bla... my other no async code
        });

        return _jsonDataResult;
    }
```

does it make sense? i just running action, and inside my any code.
I keep seeing examples that after 'await' everywhere calls "ToListAsync() or SaveChangesAsync()" - it .NET async operations. But if i dont use it, and instead it i use just await Task.Run(()=> { x= 5 +5 ;} ))  it will be asynchronous?

Answer (score 3):

> if i dont use it, and instead it i use just await Task.Run(()=> { x= 5 +5 ;} )) it will be asynchronous?

It's what I call "fake asynchrony". That is, it *acts* like it's asynchronous (returns a task which is `await`ed, and so on), but in reality it's doing *synchronous* work on another thread.

> does it make sense?

No. The only thing `await Task.Run` does on ASP.NET is cause a thread context switch for no benefits at all. So you'd slow down your response time for no reason.

For more information, see the "Asynchronous Code Is Not a Silver Bullet" section of my [article on async ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

*Generally* this does not make sense, and is not truly asynchronous on an operational level, as long as you do not have I/O operations involved. I/O operations (such as database interactions, i.e. `SaveChangesAsync` or `ToListAsync`) take much longer to complete than computations on the CPU, hence the CPU spends a relatively big amount of time waiting for I/O to complete. There's no waiting while computing 5+5 though.

Waiting blocks the whole thread when done synchronously. Async operations on the other hand do not block it, but switch to do some other work and let the OS notify it upon completion of the request. And then pick up from there again. This comes at a runtime cost too (context switching), so without actual I/O it usually doesn't help much.

Some real-life analogy:

I like Jon Skeet's pizza metaphor on async operations ([the speech is well worth watching](https://vimeo.com/37913054)): An async operation is ordering a pizza and watching TV while it's being prepared and delivered. A synchronous operation is waiting at the door until your pizza has arrived. (Or: Should you, instead of ordering pizza, just calculate 5+5 there's no point in watching TV in the middle of that operation.)

Comment: So, in web applications full benefit of Asynchronous can only be used if the system operations ( ToListAsync() e.t.c ) ? The rest of the ways (in terms of saving resources asynchrony) have no meaning?

Comment: Usually only when I/O is involved. In a nutshell you don't save resources in terms of making any operations cheaper. You can just use wait time more efficiently. I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score -1):

Generally when we use await in REST API then we will use async return type

like this:-

```
 static async void ProcessDataAsync()
    {
    // Start the HandleFile method.
    Task<int> task = HandleFileAsync("C:\\enable1.txt");

    // Control returns here before HandleFileAsync returns.
    // ... Prompt the user.
    Console.WriteLine("Please wait patiently " +
        "while I do something important.");

    // Wait for the HandleFile task to complete.
    // ... Display its results.
    int x = await task;
    Console.WriteLine("Count: " + x);
    }
```